# How to block HTTP access to a Git repository?

Tags: security, git, http, version-control, deployment

I'm playing around with the idea of using Git for deployment and updates of my web applications, but the problem is that by doing it the way I'm doing it, the .git directory (and therefore all my source code) would be accessible via HTTP. This is what is holding me back from really implementing this idea.

How do I prevent HTTP access to my Git repository?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a htaccess directive to forbid access to .git from the web.

Comment: Be sure and put this high up in your config, blocking access to *all* .git directories, rather than the common fallback of just using a single htaccess file in a single directory.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way is to not make the Git repo itself your web root, but rather a copy of it (made, perhaps, with `git archive`). You could also place the `.git` directory somewhere else in your file system, and then set the [`core.worktree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) option to your web root, so when you check out the files they will be written there (but not the `.git` directory itself).

Comment: +1 I may use this in the future, but for the time being htaccess seemed easier.